# Can I limit results using IN and COUNT?

Tags: oracle

I need to limit the results from a query, but I can't implement any example I've seen using count and rownum. Given this table

```
rec error
___ _____
  1   123
  2   123
  3   456
  4   456
  5   456
  6   456
  7   456
  8   456
  9   456
 10   789
 11   789
 12   789
 13   789
```

This table has many more rows with many different error codes. I'm using this to get the records i need:

```
select rec, error from table where error in (123,456,789)
```

But say I want to only return no more than 2 records per error. I'm not sure how to do this. If I was only looking for a single error, I could simply use count or rownum. Not sure how to do it when using the IN condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you care which two rows you get for any particular error code?  Something like this will get you the two rows for each error code with the smallest `rec` value.  If you change the `ORDER BY` in the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function, you can change which two rows are returned.

```
SELECT rec,
       error
  FROM (SELECT rec,
               error,
               row_number() over (partition by error
                                      order by rec asc) rnk
          FROM your_table_name)
 WHERE error in (123,456,789)
   AND rnk <= 2
```